# How to set system parameters for contactless communication while installing the applet?

Tags: nfc, javacard

I am trying to access my applet using the NFC interface of my mobile phone. I have two questions.

1. Consider I have a mobile phone with SWP connected to the SIM card. What are the necessary steps to do to enable applet selection and interaction through NFC port?
   Is that enough just to set the system parameters to ISD while installing the applet? (**install[for install and make selectable]**)
2. What is wrong with APDUs I send to the card while installing the applet? below are the steps I do to install the formerly loaded cap file:

- **INITIALIZE UPDATE**
- **EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATION**
- Sending **install[for install and make selectable]** APDUs as scenarios below:

If I send install APDU without system parameters:

```
<< 80 E6 0C 00 25 07 E0 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 01 08 E0 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 01 02 08 E0 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 01 02 01 00 07 C9 05 08 31 32 33 34 00 00
>> 00 90 00
```

applet is successfully installed with application parameters set in the APDU.

The problem is when I try to set system parameters for contactless communication. After INITIALIZE UPDATE and EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATION I send:

```
<< 80 E6 0C 00 2D 07 E0 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 01 08 E0 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 01 02 08 E0 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 01 02 01 00 10 EF 07 A0 05 A5 03 82 01 FF C9 05 08 31 32 33 34 00 00
>> 6A 80
```

same result is obtained if I remove application parameters.
What's wrong with my system parameters? each time I try to set contactless parameters, I get `6A 80` (wrong data) status code.

Can anyone please help me to fix this?